# TPLink AX3000 not working with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.8.

I have a Gigabyte B460M DS3H motherboard with a Core I5 CPU.
I have installed a TPLink AX3000 Wifi 6 adapter that uses Intel's AX200 chipset. It is installed in the (only) PCIe slot.

The Bluetooth works but the wifi does not. There is no Wireless option that appears in the settings menu.

I tried to install the driver from backports but it failed to build-- the error message said it was not the right kernel version.

I tried to download firmware from Intel for the AX200 chipset. I copied the downloaded file to the `/lib/firmware` directory. After a reboot, it did not make any difference. Intel's website says the driver should be included in 5.1 and later kernels.

Here is the output of `dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[    5.426908] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.434577] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.435496] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    5.435506] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[    5.435508] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.435509] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.435700] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.435723] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    5.453530] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    6.482237] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c11, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    6.482246] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x80480218
[    6.482254] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x104
[    6.482255] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired.
[    6.482324] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    6.482325] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6
[    6.482326] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode
[    6.482327] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[    6.482327] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x002022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    6.482328] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    6.482328] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004FA34A | branchlink2
[    6.482329] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink1
[    6.482330] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4BBC | interruptlink2
[    6.482330] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | data1
[    6.482331] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2
[    6.482331] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[    6.482332] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    6.482333] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000AFBD | tsf low
[    6.482333] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    6.482334] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    6.482334] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00010CD2 | time gp2
[    6.482335] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    6.482336] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | uCode version major
[    6.482336] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | uCode version minor
[    6.482337] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version
[    6.482337] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C89000 | board version
[    6.482338] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x8001FF03 | hcmd
[    6.482339] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    6.482339] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    6.482340] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[    6.482340] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    6.482341] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    6.482342] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    6.482342] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3F8A | wait_event
[    6.482343] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    6.482343] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration
[    6.482344] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    6.482344] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    6.482345] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    6.482346] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    6.482346] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000F81C | flow_handler
[    6.482370] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    6.482371] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    6.482371] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x20100222 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    6.482372] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    6.482373] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80465826 | umac branchlink2
[    6.482373] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0086AC0 | umac interruptlink1
[    6.482374] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    6.482374] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1
[    6.482375] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
[    6.482376] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[    6.482376] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000037 | umac major
[    6.482377] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD9698065 | umac minor
[    6.482377] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00010CC4 | frame pointer
[    6.482378] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886ADC | stack pointer
[    6.482378] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    6.482379] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    6.482384] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    6.482386] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    6.482389] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    6.482391] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    6.482394] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    6.482396] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    6.482399] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    6.482401] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    6.482403] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    6.482406] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.482410] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.482415] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    6.482420] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    6.482422] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    6.846238] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

It looks like the firmware is not being loaded.

What else should I do to try to get it running?

Comment: 5.8 is a no-longer supported *generic* kernel for Ubuntu 20.04 (it was a HWE kernel for 20.04.2, but upgrades moved you to 5.11 at 20.04.3 as the 5.8 kernel is no longer patched or supported. Are you using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? or if you are, why aren't you using a fully-upgraded system? or what details are missing from your question as facts provided don't match an updated 20.04 system.

Comment: Where exactly did you download the driver?  Is it for Linux/Ubuntu?  Are there installation instructions?